# Rails multiple nested routes for model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have these models:

```
Product, belongs_to :category, belongs_to :shop
Category, has_many :products
Shop, has_many :products
```

And I want to have this endpoints:

```
/products/:category_id  #all products for a category
/products/:shop_id   #all products for a shop
```

Is this possible, with a conditional in routes maybe? Or should I use different endpoints?

Comment: Are `category_id` and `shop_id` collisions possible?

Comment: I kinda solved it with route constraint and yes, since collision is possible i'm gonna use uuid. If you have a better solution you are welcome to post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a single endpoint not a very good idea as it will be ambiguous if the id segment is a category or a shop id or even a product id. It also clashes with the entire idea in REST that `/things/:id` should give you a member of that collection.

In the Rails conventions (and REST in general) you would simply create multiple [nested resources](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```
/categories/:category_id/products
/shops/:shop_id/products
```

You can do this by simply nesting the calls to the resources macro:

```
resources :categories do
  resources :products, only: [:new, :create, :index]
end

resources :shops do 
  resources :products, only: [:new, :create, :index]
end
```

This will generate the named route helpers `category_products_path` and `shop_products_path`.

Remember that any given model can have various endpoints that describe its relations with other models and any endpoint that does more then one specific task should be treated as a code smell.

Comment: Protip is to use the `module:` option on the routes if you want to point them to different controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

routes:

```
class CategoryConstraint
  def self.matches?(request)
    Category.where(id: request.path_parameters[:id]).any?
  end
end

 post 'products/:id', to: 'products#category_products', constraints: CategoryConstraint
 post 'products/:id', to: 'products#shop_products'
```

If anybody has a better solution I will accept it.